# Jupyter terminats/exits with an error

Tags: python, jupyter

Recently, whenever I terminate Jupyter by hitting `CTRL-C` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(notebook.notebookapp.main())
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1247, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 862, in start
^C  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 122, in poll
    z_events = self._poller.poll(1000*timeout)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zmq/sugar/poll.py", line 99, in poll
    return zmq_poll(self.sockets, timeout=timeout)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/_poll.pyx", line 123, in zmq.backend.cython._poll.zmq_poll (zmq/backend/cython/_poll.c:2186)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/_poll.pyx", line 116, in zmq.backend.cython._poll.zmq_poll (zmq/backend/cython/_poll.c:2036)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 12, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc (zmq/backend/cython/_poll.c:2418)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/gateways/signals.py", line 15, in conda_signal_handler
    raise CondaSignalInterrupt(signum)
conda.exceptions.CondaSignalInterrupt: Signal interrupt SIGINT
```

I tried to search a little for some hint what's the cause or reason but for vain. Therefore, I ask you. Do you know what's the reason?